# Setting Selected Value of DropDownList in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have gone through numerous methods of trying to set the value of a dropdownlist and must be doing something silly because none of the methods are working.

```
@Html.DropDownList("startTime", @Model.startTimeList, new { @class = "startTime", style = "width: 100px;" })
```

Its a generated list of half hour increments.

In my controller I set this string value..

```
model.startTime = myTime + " " + amOrPm;  //ex 10:30 PM
```

My List looks like this.

```
List<SelectListItem> startTimeList = new List<SelectListItem>();    

SelectListItem time12 = new SelectListItem { Text = "12:00 PM", Selected = false, Value = "12:00PM" };
startTimeList.Add(time12);

SelectListItem time12Half = new SelectListItem { Text = "12:30 PM", Selected = false, Value = "12:30PM" };
startTimeList.Add(time12Half);
```

My list always defaults to 12:00 PM because its the first one entered into the list.  I want that if model.startTime has a value it sets to that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a startTime property on your model, and the value of that property matches one of the values in the list (ie, it matches "12:00PM", or "12:30PM" but not "12:00 PM" or "12:30 PM"), then I think this *should* work:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.startTime, 
    @Model.startTimeList, 
    new { @class = "startTime", style = "width: 100px;" })
```

Comment: Both are right but this ended up pointing me to the real problem.  I was trying to match 06:00 to 6:00.  I knew it had to be something silly, didn't realize it was adding the leading 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DropDownListFor` and let the Razor engine do the work of selecting the item that matches the property.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.startTime, startTimeList)
```

---

The alternative would be to explicitly set `Selected` on the item that matches:

```
startTimeList.First(item => item.Text.Equals(model.startTime)).Selected = true;
```